# How can I fix 'integrity constraint (PROD_SUP_FK) violated - parent key not found'?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I did this

```
INSERT INTO product (prod_id, prod_price, prod_avail, prod_mdate, prod_edate, cust_id, sto_id, sup_id)
Values('RBL01001',4.50,'Available',TO_DATE('29-MAR-21','DD-MON-YY'),TO_DATE('29-APR-21','DD-MON-YY'),0001,'Kapar1','SUPP-001');
```

and this is the result

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (PROD_SUP_FK) violated - parent key not found

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (PROD_SUP_FK) violated - parent key not found

> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

> INSERT INTO product (prod_id, prod_price, prod_avail, prod_mdate, prod_edate, cust_id, sto_id, sup_id)
> Values('RBL01001',4.50,'Available',TO_DATE('29-MAR-21','DD-MON-YY'),TO_DATE('29-APR-21','DD-MON-YY'),0001,'Kapar1','SUPP-001');

Table product

```
CREATE TABLE product
 (
   prod_id      VARCHAR2 (10) CONSTRAINT prod_id_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
   prod_price   NUMBER (3, 2) CONSTRAINT prod_price_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
   prod_avail   VARCHAR2 (20) CONSTRAINT prod_avail_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
   prod_mdate   DATE CONSTRAINT prod_mdate_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
   prod_edate   DATE CONSTRAINT prod_edate_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
   cust_id      NUMBER (4, 0),
   sto_id       VARCHAR (8) CONSTRAINT sto_id_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
   sup_id       VARCHAR (10),
   CONSTRAINT prod_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (prod_id) USING INDEX ENABLE,
   CONSTRAINT prod_date_interval CHECK (prod_edate > prod_mdate) ENABLE
 );
```

table supplier

```
CREATE TABLE  supplier
(
  sup_id VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT sup_id_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
  sup_name VARCHAR2(500) CONSTRAINT sup_name_NN NOT NULL ENABLE,
  sup_add VARCHAR2(500) CONSTRAINT sup_add_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
  CONSTRAINT sup_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (sup_id) USING INDEX  ENABLE
);
```

Alter table product

```
ALTER TABLE  product ADD CONSTRAINT prod_cust_fk FOREIGN KEY (cust_id)
        REFERENCES  customer (cust_id) ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE  product ADD CONSTRAINT prod_sto_fk FOREIGN KEY (sto_id)
        REFERENCES  bakery / store (sto_id) ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE  product ADD CONSTRAINT prod_sup_fk FOREIGN KEY (sup_id)
        REFERENCES  supplier (sup_id) ENABLE;

CREATE INDEX  prod_cust_ix ON  product (cust_id);
CREATE INDEX  prod_sto_ix ON  product (sto_id);
CREATE INDEX  prod_sup_ix ON  product (sup_id);
```

using Oracle APEX 21.2.0

Comment: The value `SUPP-001` doesn't seem to exist in your supplier table.

Comment: [**ORA-02291**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e2100.htm#1004903): **Cause**: A foreign key value has no matching primary key value. **Action**: Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key. Please, check the definition of [foreign key](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/data-integrity.html#GUID-7CD73D16-EA1A-4AA8-AA7D-4288557395B8) constraint

Comment: Just as an aside, I find this construct to be very troubling:  "TO_DATE('29-MAR-21','DD-MON-YY')".  2-digit years?  Really?  Perhaps you are too young to remember, and your tech education has failed you miserably.  But I (and thousands like me) spent far too much of my life in 1998 and 1999 modifying systems to prevent failure resulting from the use of 2-digit years.  And it was not a matter of 'set it and forget it'.  And to this day we keep seeing problems resulting from people who have forgotten or never knew the lessons of 'Y2K'.

Comment: @EdStevens Thanks for the heads-up sir, just recapped a little bit in my mind that I've learnt about that date issue arisen and there's RR format.  And I was just following the date format that usually seen for this product type. I am sort of new to SQL and trying to be better

Comment: The RR format (and RRRR) were meant to buy some time for systems that couldn't fully remediate Y2k.  Oracle maintains it as a default, but it is LOOOOONNNNNGGGG past time to continue to rely on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to insert rows into "master" tables (`customer`, `supplier`, `bakery`/`store`), then into their "child" table (`product`).

---

By the way, what is this `bakery / store` thing supposed to do? Such a syntax is invalid:

```
ALTER TABLE  product ADD CONSTRAINT prod_sto_fk FOREIGN KEY (sto_id)
    REFERENCES  bakery / store (sto_id) ENABLE;
                --------------
                this
```

Comment: I see, I thought the product table is the master table. You do recognise these tables are from an ERD in my previous question? Mistake on the table name, just 'store'

Comment: "master" and "child" are (in my answer) terms that refer to foreign key constraints. Tables that are referenced are "master". I didn't check your previous questions; no problem if PRODUCT actually is a master table (regarding the whole data model).

Comment: @Litllefoot Understood ^